# Finding lost Outlook folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I’ve been Googling to find a solution to this problem, and can see that many other people have asked this same question, but so far have not found any answers that were useful (either to the person posting the query or to me).

At some stage recently I must have accidentally moved one of my Outlook folders to somewhere else.  You’d imagine I just accidentally pushed it inside another folder, but manual searching has so far not found it. It's an important folder containing numerous sub-folders.

Using the normal Search All Mail Items facility for likely terms, I can find numerous mail items from within the sub-folders (thus confirming I have not deleted it/them).  I can open these items from the search results box, and Properties tells me the name of the folder (though I already knew that from the search results box).  But it does not give me any directory tree that I could use to trace back to the folder’s location.

I’ve tried searching on terms from the folder name, but this does not turn up anything relevant – evidently Outlook only searches in mail items, not in folder names.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

***... a few hours later:***

OK, our IT support guys have found the answer.  You have to:

(a) enable instant searching in Outlook (took a couple of hours to complete indexing), and

(b) enable Windows Desktop Search.
The latter will search for a folder name, and also displays the directory tree for the folder.

Lost folder found, problem solved.
Cheers.

... and for the person who asked:  Windows XP Pro ver 5.1;  MS Office Outlook 2007;  Unicode / Microsoft Exchange;  and from memory I think it's a POP account but this info seems to be hidden from users at present.

Comment: I don't know an answer offhand, but I do know enough to say that it may be relevant to post what version of Outlook you're running and what type of email account this is (IMAP? POP?).  Please edit that information into the post.

Comment: You should post the answer as an actual answer, and then accept it when you're able to do so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

... a few hours later:

OK, our IT support guys have found the answer. You have to:

(a) enable instant searching in Outlook (took a couple of hours to complete indexing), and

(b) enable Windows Desktop Search.
The latter will search for a folder name, and also displays the directory tree for the folder.

Lost folder found, problem solved.
Cheers.

... and for the person who asked: Windows XP Pro ver 5.1; MS Office Outlook 2007; Unicode / Microsoft Exchange; and from memory I think it's a POP account but this info seems to be hidden from users at present.